Instagram Open graph API: Access to publish data but not to read
Problem: When making a GET request to Instagram Graph API I get the following error:

{"message":"(#10) Application does not have permission for this action","type":"OAuthException","code":10....}

I'm sending requests from a route handler in a React Node.js application. I can publish content and get content through the following endpoint
https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{ig-user-id}/media
using the same access_token. How can I have access to publishing content but not access to read a parameter?
Ex. Of what works:
const res = await fetch("https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{ig-user-id}/media?access_token={access_token}");  
      
const response = await res.json();

Ex. Of what does not work:
const res = await fetch("https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{ig-user-id}?fields=shopping_product_tag_eligibility&access_token={access_token}");        

const response = await res.json();

Any idea of why this doesn't work?
I checked the permissions and they are the following:

manage_fundraisers
publish_video
catalog_management
pages_manage_cta
pages_manage_instant_articles
pages_show_list
read_page_mailboxes
ads_management
ads_read
business_management
pages_messaging
pages_messaging_subscriptions
instagram_basic
instagram_manage_comments
instagram_manage_insights
instagram_content_publish
leads_retrieval
instagram_manage_messages
page_events
pages_read_engagement
pages_manage_metadata
pages_read_user_content
pages_manage_ads
pages_manage_posts
pages_manage_engagement
instagram_branded_content_brand
instagram_branded_content_creator
instagram_branded_content_ads_brand
instagram_manage_events

So I think there shouldn't be a problem with the permissions.
